# Flutter build error: Error connecting to the service protocol: failed to connect to http://127.0.0.1:51234/v9-zOlh23aE=/

Tags: flutter

My app build failed with the following build error:

```
√ Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.

D/FlutterLocationService(29765): Creating service.

D/FlutterLocationService(29765): Binding to location service.

Error connecting to the service protocol: failed to connect to http://127.0.0.1:51234/v9-zOlh23aE=/

Exited (sigterm)
```

this happened after pub upgrade.

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69730208/9942927. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Though this issue seems to be common and can be caused by various situations, maybe you should check whether the SDK is selected.

In Android Studio, you can set the SDK in `File -> Project Structure -> Project SDK`, which works in my case.

Or else you can also try `flutter clean && flutter upgrade`.